# Relativity collision problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, kinematics, collision

Here is the problem:

A body of mass m (I assumed this is rest mass, but not 100%), and momentum p(subscript m) collides with a stationary particle of mass M. Find the available energy in the CM frame. Find the momentum of the particle of mass m in the CM frame in terms of M, p(subscript m), and s. (s = (sum E)^2 - (vector sum p)^2).

Apparently the answer to the second bit is Mp(subscript m)/s.

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: How is this special-relativity? It sure seem like home-work without much effort.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: Hey Frisbee, your quite right that it was a homework problem. The conceptual interest is meant to be what part of the SR framework actually gives an answer to this, and whether there is a reason for the form (namely why would the momentum in the CM frame be proportional to the ratio of M to s.) I kinda spent the best part of yesterday on it, and could only get an equation for the energy of the paricle, and its momentum didn't come out in the right form, so I was wondering if I was missing something.  But I hadn't realised that explicit homeworks were meant for other sites - thanks!

Comment: dmanning, you need to show that you have made some effort to work through the problem and what you're specifically having an issue with. you can get help with homework, just not get someone to write solutions for you